# Rearranging numbered cards to reverse their order

Tags: combinatorics, induction, contest-math

I have been thinking about this question for a long time, but I can't solve it.
Here is the question:

> We have $9$ cards, with numbers one to nine written on them (in the order $1, 2, \ldots , 9$).
>
> You can move $n$ cards, if they are located next to each other (physically, not numerically).

First, I have to show how to make it $9, 8, 7, \ldots, 1$ in five moves and then prove that it is possible.

Sorry for any spelling and grammar errors, improper tags or any other mistake.

---

An example of a valid move:

We pick cards $1,2,3,4$ and put them between $7$ and $8$. The sequence after the move looks like this: $$5,6,7,1,2,3,4,8,9.$$

Comment: It's not totally clear what you mean by *'You can move $n$ cards if they are located next to each other'*. What are the valid moves you can do to the sequence of numbers $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_9$? (I hope my edits haven't changed the meaning of your question - they were mostly formatting and grammar changes).

Comment: @DanielRust hi. thanks for the edit . I made an example of a correct move. hope it helps

Comment: is it clear enough?

Comment: Is the move from 123456789 to 145672389 legal?

Comment: @Did yes. it is a legal move

Comment: @Did so it is probably my mistake. :| sorry

Comment: sorry @DanielRust . I wrongfully blamed you . but I can't understand how I forgot to put the most important part...

Comment: Are you sure this is possible?

Comment: It should be. It was in a Contest .

Comment: If you show how to do it, that proves it is possible.  Is the proof supposed to be that there is not a shorter solution?

Comment: @RossMillikan first you have to show it's possible, then find a shorter way to prove it without considering every move

Comment: @soheils It does not look like your statement is true. Most likely, you have not described the moves correctly. Can you tell us the source of the problem and the exact problem statement?

Comment: @Phira unfortunately, the source statement is not in English,but In persian. however, I am quite sure this is a correct statement.